# Apache server to host php panel

Tags: php, apache, server

I have a php admin panel for a voip client I'm using (https://github.com/dieonar/MyMumb-Panel) running on a Raspi2 with Apache2 on it. 
I'm kind of new to hosting but I mainly want to use it on my local net, and thus writing 192.168.0.111/MyMumb-Panel (rasp pi local address) would direct me to this site.

However, while 192...111/index.html works fine, going to /MyMumb-Panel/index.php shows a blank page. I havent written the php module personally but I'm fairly sure it should work OOB..

I have low knowledge of apache and usually use WAMP, but sicne this is on linux, I'm confused with what inis to configure and so on..

Can someone give me pointers as to where to begin ? There's a readme on the git with instructions, which I've followed, but there's some confusion regarding Vhosts and configuring these..